# How do I pass environment variable to Codeception YML file from command line?

Tags: codeception

I see this sort of thing in Codeception YML files all the time:

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: '%URL%'
```

How do I pass "URL" to Codeception from the command line? Or any other way!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is documented at https://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers#Dynamic-Configuration-With-Parameters

> Modules can be dynamically configured from environment variables.
>   Parameter storage should be specified in the global codeception.yml
>   configuration inside the params section. Parameters can be loaded from
>   environment vars, from yaml (Symfony format), .env (Laravel format),
>   ini, or php files.
>
> Use the params section of the global configuration file
>   codeception.yml to specify how to load them. You can specify several
>   sources for parameters to be loaded from.
>
> Example: load parameters from the environment:
>
> ```
> params:
>     - env # load params from environment vars
> ```
>
> Example: load parameters from YAML file (Symfony):
>
> ```
> params:
>     - app/config/parameters.yml
> ```
>
> Example: load parameters from php file (Yii)
>
> ```
> params:
>     - config/params.php
> ```
>
> Example: load parameters from .env files (Laravel):
>
> ```
> params:
>     - .env
>     - .env.testing
> ```
>
> Once loaded, parameter variables can be used as module configuration
>   values. Use a variable name wrapped with % as a placeholder and it
>   will be replaced by its value.
>
> Let’s say we want to specify credentials for a cloud testing service.
>   We have loaded SAUCE_USER and SAUCE_KEY variables from environment,
>   and now we are passing their values into config of WebDriver:
>
> ```
> modules:
>    enabled:
>       - WebDriver:
>          url: http://example.com
>          host: '%SAUCE_USER%:%SAUCE_KEY%@ondemand.saucelabs.com'
> ```
>
> Parameters are also useful to provide connection credentials for the
>   Db module (taken from Laravel’s .env files):
>
> ```
> modules:
>     enabled:
>         - Db:
>             dsn: "mysql:host=%DB_HOST%;dbname=%DB_DATABASE%"
>             user: "%DB_USERNAME%"
>             password: "%DB_PASSWORD%"
> ```

If you want to set it in command line, you can set it like this:

```
URL=http://example.org codecept run
```

or

```
export URL=http://example.org
codecept run
```

Examples above work with Bash, you may have todo something else if you use a different shell.